# How to calculate SPL change from a sound source to a listening position?

Tags: speakers, sound, pressure

I need to know how to calculate SPL change from a sound source to a listening position. I already know the distance between the speaker and the listening position and also the SPL at the speaker.

Comment: What is SPL? Could you please provide more information?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent Sound Pressure Level.

Answer (score 1):

Sound pressure follows the inverse square law. You mention that you know the sound pressure at the source, but usually the pressure would be specified at some distance, typically 1 meter. In that case the SPL at some distance D meters away would be 1/D^2 times the pressure at 1 meter. If the SPL of your source is specified using a different distance or units, adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. On the PDF I have, the information consists of a "SPL at the membrane of speaker" and also "Virtual point Distance". Does this mean that the SPL at the membrane is measured at Virtual point distance?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a spherical wavefront, the sound pressure level (SPL) decays as:
$$1/r^2$$
This is called the inverse square, and is common in these types of analysis.

Every doubling of the distance should reduce the SPL by 6 db.

For more details and exceptions to this rule:  [LINK](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-SoundAndDistance.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Already checked that link before, But I'm still not sure how exactly is the equation. I know SPL decrease is proportional to the 1/r^2 but is it exactly equal?

Comment: No, but very close to it.  What that means is we are ignoring real world effect that would GREATLY complicate our calculations.  Pretending your speaker is a point source will get you close to the actual value without making you spend months calculating.